# Fluctuation-dissipation theorem in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, solid-state-physics, greens-functions, fluctuation-dissipation

If I understand correctly, the [fluctuation-dissipation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem) (fdt) in QFT technically arises because of $\pm i\epsilon$ - infinitesimally small summand in the denominator of spectral representation of Green functions. By comparing with the derivation of fdt for oscillator with friction and external force, I see that $i\epsilon$ causes dissipation as well as the friction term for harmonic oscillator.

What is the physical reasoning of such phenomena (there are dissipations in almost free quantum systems)?

Comment: I don't think that any sort of regularization for the purposes of integration can be used to derive the fluctuation-dissipation theorem. The physical reasons for it are thermodynamic and relativistic in nature: we have $kT>0$ even in quantum systems and for an open system there is always a dissipative solution because we are losing energy towards infinity in form of radiation.

Comment: Here is a [relevant post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138217/complex-integration-by-shifting-the-contour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fluctuation-dissipation theorem is a relation between the symmetrized
and retarded correlation functions 
$$
G_s(\omega,k)=\coth\left(\frac{\omega}{2T}\right) 
\,{\rm Im}\, G_R(\omega,k).
$$
I would not say that it is due to the "$i\epsilon$" terms. The $i\epsilon$ simply reflects the different analyticity properties of $G_{R,A}$ etc. Physically, the symmetrized correlator is a measure of fluctuations, and the retarded correlator is a measure of dissipation. For example, the retarded correlator of the stress tensor determines viscosity
$$
\eta(\omega) =\frac{1}{\omega}{\rm Im}\, G_R(\omega,0)\, . 
$$ 
Why should this be true? Imagine a particle, a harmonic oscillator, or a quantum field coupled to a reservoir at some temperature $T$. In the equations of motion, this is reflected by a noise term. Without dissipation, the noise would continue to pump energy into the system, so in thermal equilibrium the noise must be balanced by a dissipative term in the equations of motion.