# Pole of a free-particle propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions

The free-particle propagator is given by
$$\Delta_F(x-y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^4} \int \frac{e^{-ik\cdot(x-y)}}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon} \, d^4k.$$

In the book *Quantum Field Theory*, Ryder says that $\Delta_F(x-y)$ has a pole at $k^2=m^2$ (page 203).

However, the pole is actually at $k^2=m^2 - i\epsilon$. Why is the $-i\epsilon$ term not mentioned?

Comment: [This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138217/complex-integration-by-shifting-the-contour) will certainly help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't have the book, but usually the $i \epsilon$ is added intentionally (and artificially) to address the pole, and bring it off the real axis.  Somewhere later in the calculation, you take the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Very true. There's a discussion of this issue here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138217/complex-integration-by-shifting-the-contour

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the link! It's a very nice and clear discussion.