# Can time period for pendulum be negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, time, conventions, oscillators

For a pendulum, a= acceleration, y= displacement, w= angular velocity, T= time period. 
We have 
→|a| = yw²
→a/y = w² = (2π/T) ²
→2π/T = +√(a/y) or -√(a/y) 
→T= + 2π√(y/a) or -2π√(y/a). Is this correct that time period can be negative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of negative frequency for the sake of simplifying mathematics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362719/) because period is inverse of frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, The period is just the amount of time it takes for a whole oscillation. You can, for classical mechanics like this, just take the equations of motion and switch the time argument for $-t$, and still have the physics work, but the *amount* of time between oscillations is still going to be $T,$ and more to the point I'm not really sure why you would want a negative $T$ even if you justify defining one.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we write the equation of motion as:

$$ y = A \sin(\omega t) = A \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{T} t \right) $$

If the period $T$ is a positive number then the variation of $y$ with time looks like this:

[image: Positive T]

If we keep the magnitude of $T$ the same but make it a negative number then we get this:

[image: Negative T]

which is the same graph just shifted along the time axis by $\pi$. So yes you can make $T$ negative if you wish. The initial conditions will determine which is correct i.e. is the velocity positive or negative when $t=0$?

Having said this, we wouldn't normally talk about a negative period. If we wanted the second graph we'd probably keep $T$ as a positive number and write the equation with a phase shift i.e.

$$ y = A \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{T} t + \pi \right) $$

Comment: But what is the physical meaning of negative time period? Is it the same as negative time in kinematics when we count the time in reverse?